# Drupal table from DataBase

Tags: drupal, view

I am new to Drupal and working on this project of mine. I created a webform which stores information about an event. I want to create a view to display certain columns of the form, and when someone clicks the title a pop-up will be created with more information about the event.

My current form looks like:

[image]

My Goal for viewing the data looks like:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that you have installed Views and you are familiar with creating a Views Table.The module [Popup Views integration](https://www.drupal.org/project/popup_views_integration) supports this feature. You need to have Views and PopUp modules installed first.